# PySpark PicklingError

Tags: apache-kafka, pyspark, pickle, rdd

I am seeing a pickling error:

> Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required.

Below is the trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 62, in call
    r = self.func(t, *rdds)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py", line 159, in 
    func = lambda t, rdd: old_func(rdd)
    if rdd.count() > 0:
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1006, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 997, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 871, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 773, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2388, in _jrdd
    pickled_cmd, bvars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(self.ctx, command, self)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2308, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 428, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 646, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 111, in dump
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
   PicklingError: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required.
```

Here is part of my code inn highlevel which caused the error:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="my_app")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

kafka_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, full_topic_list, kafka_params, fromOffsets=offset_dict)

messages = kafka_stream.map(lambda (k, v): json.loads(v))

messages.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: process(rdd, topic_list, sqlcontext))
```

In my process function, there is a rdd count: `if topic_rdd.count() > 0`, which throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass RDDs to and process RDDs in the distributed functions (maps, reduces, etc).

Comment: Thanks cftarnas. What is the best way to perform function for a rdd though if i pass RDD.

Comment: @ling: You really can't pass the RDDs, they are not pickleable. How to solve your overall problem depends on what you are trying to do, a more detailed code snippet could help. It could as simple as pre-calculating the topic_rdd.count() first then just pass the counts themselves.